# Рекурсивный запрос

Tags: postgresql

В общем, имею рекурсивный запрос:

```
WITH RECURSIVE temp1 ( p_id,p_parent,p_title,PATH, LEVEL, NAME  ) AS (
SELECT T1.p_id,T1.p_parent, T1.p_title, CAST (T1.p_id AS VARCHAR (50)) as PATH, 1 , CAST (T1.p_title AS VARCHAR (255)) as NAME
    FROM "SC_Wonder".t_page T1 WHERE T1.p_parent IS NULL
union
select T2.p_id, T2.p_parent, T2.p_title, CAST ( temp1.PATH ||'->'|| T2.p_id AS VARCHAR(50)) ,LEVEL + 1 ,
CAST (  '   '|| temp1.NAME AS VARCHAR(255))
     FROM "SC_Wonder".t_page T2 INNER JOIN temp1 ON( temp1.p_id= T2.p_parent))
select * from temp1 ORDER BY PATH LIMIT 100
```

Он выдает

в поле NAME

```
_10

______10
```

и прочее.

Причем 10 - это имя первой записи.
Как победить и заставить выводить имя текущей записи?

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH RECURSIVE temp1 ( p_id,p_parent,p_title,PATH, LEVEL, NAME  ) AS (
SELECT T1.p_id,T1.p_parent, T1.p_title, CAST (T1.p_id AS VARCHAR (50)) as PATH, 1 , 
CAST (T1.p_title AS VARCHAR (255)) as NAME
    FROM "SC_Wonder".t_page T1 WHERE T1.p_parent IS NULL
union
select T2.p_id, T2.p_parent, T2.p_title, CAST ( temp1.PATH ||'->'|| T2.p_id AS VARCHAR(50)) ,LEVEL + 1 ,
CAST (  lpad('', (LEVEL + 1)*3, ' ') || T2.p_title AS VARCHAR(255))
     FROM "SC_Wonder".t_page T2 INNER JOIN temp1 ON( temp1.p_id= T2.p_parent))
select * from temp1 ORDER BY PATH LIMIT 100
```

соль в

```
CAST (  lpad('', (LEVEL + 1)*3, ' ') || T2.p_title AS VARCHAR(255))
```

Answer (score 0):

Может, так:

```
WITH RECURSIVE temp1 ( p_id,p_parent,p_title,PATH, LEVEL, NAME  ) AS (
SELECT T1.p_id,T1.p_parent, T1.p_title, CAST (T1.p_id AS VARCHAR (50)) as PATH, 1 , CAST (T1.p_title AS VARCHAR (255)) as NAME
FROM "SC_Wonder".t_page T1 WHERE T1.p_parent IS NULL
union
select T2.p_id, T2.p_parent, T2.p_title, CAST ( temp1.PATH ||'->'|| T2.p_id AS VARCHAR(50)) ,LEVEL + 1 ,
CAST (  '   '|| T2.NAME AS VARCHAR(255))
FROM "SC_Wonder".t_page T2 INNER JOIN temp1 ON( temp1.p_id= T2.p_parent))
select * from temp1 ORDER BY PATH LIMIT 100
```

То есть при выводе очередной записи брать поле Name из T2.

Comment: ERROR:  column t2.name does not exist
LINE 1: ....p_id AS VARCHAR(50)) ,LEVEL + 1 , CAST ( '   '|| T2.NAME AS...

Comment: mea culpa, затупил, поле же у вас p_title... тогда CAST (  '   '||T2.p_title AS VARCHAR(255))

Comment: я пробовал таким образом, тогда иерархичность не проходит.
можно реализовать что-то вроде <b>' '*level <b>?

Comment: Что значит не проходит? В каком виде данные выводятся?